# How to set a Map value in h:inputText

Tags: jsf, dictionary, jstl

I'm struggling to implement a fairly trivial functionality with JSF which involves dynamically displaying the content of a nested map on a page and editing capabilities for its values. But it has turned out that the `MappedValueExpression$Entry` that you get when iterating over a map with `c:forEach` is not writable!

```
<c:forEach items='#{inflectionBean.word.inflectionalForms}' var="number" >
    <p:fieldset legend="#{number.key}">
        <c:forEach items="#{number.value}" var="case" >
            <p:panel header="#{case.key}">
                <h:inputText value="#{case.value}" />
            </p:panel>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:fieldset>
</c:forEach>
```

When I am trying to submit the above form I'm getting:

> javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /inflection.xhtml @39,56 value="#{case.value}": The class 'com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.MappedValueExpression$Entry' does not have a writable property 'value'.

I wonder if there are reasonable workarounds or if I am approaching the problem in a wrong way. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, what your code is attempting is invoking [`Map.Entry#setValue(value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#setValue%28V%29). This is indeed not possible in EL. Instead, you should be referencing the map value directly on the map itself by key, so that EL can do [`Map#put(key, value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29).

```
<c:forEach items="#{number.value}" var="case">
    ...
    <h:inputText value="#{number.value[case.key]}" />
```

Comment: I actually tried going away from using braces as I had problems with like `#{inflectionBean.word.inflectionalForms[numberKey][caseKey]}`, but thanks so much, it worked!

Comment: I'm not sure how that would ever cause problems, but you're welcome :)

Comment: I would be drawing keys from other two lists and hit the `inaccessible null resolved to null` in hope to initialize the map this way...