# f:selectOneMenu with parameter

Tags: jsf

I have a set of groups (of users) and a table where I display these groups (and users). Each groups table header includes a `f:selectOneMenu` which allows to set a group-wide value. For the sake of this example, let it be a list of int values (0, 5, 10, 15, 20). Below the short version of things

Pojos:

```
public class User {
    private int    id;
    private String name;
    // .. getter, setter, equals, hashCode
}  

public class Group {
    private int    id;
    private String name;
    // .. getter, setter, equals, hashCode
}
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "oneSelectController")
@ViewScoped
public class OneSelectController implements Serializable {

    private List<User>                users;
    private List<Group>               groups;
    private List<Integer>             values;
    private Map<Group, List<User>>    usersToGroup;
    private Map<Group, List<Integer>> valuesToGroup;

    public OneSelectController() {

        log.info("New " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " ...");

        users = new ArrayList<>(4);
        users.add(new User(1, "User 1"));
        users.add(new User(2, "User 2"));
        users.add(new User(3, "User 3"));
        users.add(new User(4, "User 4"));

        groups = new ArrayList<>(5);
        groups.add(new Group(1, "Group 1"));
        groups.add(new Group(2, "Group 2"));
        groups.add(new Group(3, "Group 3"));
        groups.add(new Group(4, "Group 4"));
        groups.add(new Group(5, "Group 5"));

        values = Arrays.asList(0, 5, 10, 15, 20);

        usersToGroup = new HashMap<>();
        valuesToGroup = new HashMap<>();

        for (Group g : groups) {
            usersToGroup.put(g, users);
            valuesToGroup.put(g, values);
        }
    }

    public List<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public Integer getValueByGroup(Group group) {
        // return value for given group
    }

    public List<Integer> getValuesByGroup(Group group) {
        // return list of possible values
    }
}
```

XHTML:

```
<p:dataTable id="userTable"
             var="user"
             value="#{oneSelectController.users}">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <div>User</div>
        </f:facet>
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.name}"/>
        </div>
    </p:column>
    <p:columns id="groups" value="#{oneSelectController.groups}" var="group">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <div>#{group.name}</div>
            <div>
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{oneSelectController.getValueByGroup(group)}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{oneSelectController.getValuesByGroup(group)}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </div>
        </f:facet>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

How do I set up a working setter for the `h:selectOneMenu`? Whatever I do, I end up with exceptions. The setter (somehow) must be capable to take the value selected, but also contain the information for which group the selection was made.

Comment: Maybe the `<f:selectItems` needs `getValuesForGroup()` instead of `getValuesByGroup()`

Comment: I think this calls for a converter and the group pojo must just include the selected value. I'll try later. The naming issue you are indicating was a 'copy-paste-change-it-for-the-example-on-sf'-issue =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getValueByGroup` is not considered a getter by JSF, since you're using it with a parameter. I think your best here is to use a Map, properly implementing the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods for `Group` class:

In your bean:

```
private Map<Group, Integer> selectedValueByGroup = new HashMap<>();
//Getter
```

In the view:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{oneSelectController.selectedValueByGroup[group]}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{oneSelectController.getValuesByGroup(group)}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Also, unrelated to the concrete question and as @Kukeltje points out, you could use a `Map` structure to manage the values to show by group as well:

In your bean:

```
private Map<Group, List<Integer>> valuesByGroup = new HashMap<>();
//Getter
```

In the view:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{oneSelectController.selectedValueByGroup[group]}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{oneSelectController.valuesByGroup[group]}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

You might consider using a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap` if the ordering is important to you too.

**See also:**

- [How to set a Map value in h:inputText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977578/how-to-set-a-map-value-in-hinputtext)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-hashmap-java/

Comment: Ahhhhhh you beat me to it ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje, I haven't answered in JSF tag since loong time, but this bounty is sweet xD Try it yourself to provide a better one!

Comment: Hahaha, no I'll just add a comment... so you can improve the answer The hashmap construction could be used for the `f:selectItems` too, removing the need for an additional getter (which effectively reads from the hashmap. And if you are at it, maybe the order of items in the maps used is relevant so suggest a LinkedHashMap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484126/how-to-display-hashmap-in-jsf-using-selectonemenu

Comment: The valuesByGroup sort of already is in the Q. It is called valuesToGroup there (and it can be an Integer, no need for SelectItem)

Comment: Not regretting to put up a bounty like this for getting a good answer. 
The current sprint is tight and I have wasted so many hours on this. I'll check it out tomorrow morning first thing. If it checks out, I'll gladly give you the 400.